# How to hide configuration management from the main function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pureconfig

I have my entry point like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  pureconfig.loadConfig[Conf] match {
    case Right(conf) => doStuff(conf)
    case Left(fail) => lectureUserAboutStuff(fail)
  }
}
```

So it looks like the main purpose of my program is to load a configuration, which is not true, the core of my program is to `doStuff`.

How to expressively represent this and hide undercover the configuration?

I would like something like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  doStuff(conf)(failHandler)
}
```

In which is clear that the failure handling and the configuration loading is just accessory.

Comment: I would argue that just becase you call `pureconfig.loadConfig` first, this means that that's the main purpose of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most common way to use PureConfig from the `main` method of your program is to fail fast in case of error. The API provides `loadConfigOrThrow` which returns the configuration if the loading has been successful and throws a `ConfigReaderException` otherwise:

```scala
import pureconfig.loadConfigOrThrow

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val conf = loadConfigOrThrow[Conf] // will throw if Conf cannot be loaded
  doStuff(conf)
}
```

The reason why `pureconfig.loadConfig` returns an `Either` is because
loading configuration can fail. `Either` models both the failure
case, with `Left`, and the success case, with `Right`. This is
good for a library, because you never know where `loadConfig`
will be called and consequently you don't want to throw an
exception. While this is true in general, when `loadConfig` is
used from a "surface" method, e.g. `main`, throwing exception or
just exiting in case of config loading failure makes sense and
that's why pureconfig provides `loadConfigOrThrow`.

In case you don't like throwing exception or you prefer a custom
failure handler, like `lectureUserAboutStuff`, you can create a
helper:

```scala
def loadConfig(): Option[Conf] = {
  val errorOrConf = pureconfig.loadConfig[Conf]
  errorOrConf.left.foreach(lectureUserAboutStuff)
  errorOrConf.toOption
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  loadConfig().foreach(doStuff)
```

One last thing to keep in mind is that a minor issue with this
code is that the exit code of the application is not affected by
configuration failures. If you want to set a exit code for when
the configuration cannot be loaded, then change `main` to

```scala
val configReaderFailureErrorCode = 42

private def configFailureExit() =
  sys.exit(configReaderFailureErrorCode)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  loadConfig().fold(configFailureExit())(doStuff)
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing answer!